# Win7 API to programmatically add a group to a security policy?

Tags: security, winapi, local-security-policy

I have found the API to add a group programmatically, the next logical step is to add this group to a security policy, such as "Create Global Objects".

What is the Win7 API to programmatically add a group to a security policy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How To Manage User Privileges Programmatically in Windows NT](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/132958)

To look up the SID for a group, use LsaLookupNames

Comment: Thank You. I tried to vote +1 but it tells me I must have 15 score for such...... Any, to help speed things along -- might you or anyone else have some example code using this newly (to me) found Lsa API to show adding a "member" to a given "policy" -- thanks in advance. All the best, Kevin Waite